# Solaris 11 nslookup reverses ip

Tags: dns

From (Solaris 11.1 with current patches, m4000 128GB) syslog:

```
Jun 17 10:06:14 sun-m4k-03 sendmail[4993]: [ID 702911 mail.warning] gethostbyaddr(10.128.4.50) failed: 1
```

The ip is valid from the commandline:

```
ping 10.128.4.50
10.128.4.50 is alive
```

nslookup appears to reverse the octets when doing a lookup:

```
 nslookup 10.128.4.50
Server:         10.128.8.18
Address:        10.128.8.18#53

** server can't find 50.4.128.10.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

Tried a search on the internet - no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct.  Reverse DNS lookups are performed by querying the `PTR` record for the IP address in the `.in-addr.arpa` domain.  DNS names have the least significant/least broad component first, so octets of the IP address, which are written with the most significant/most broad component first, are put in the reverse order so that each class of network can have a DNS zones.

If you want to support reverse DNS lookups on private IP addresses, you will have to configure a zone for `10.in-addr.arpa.` to hold the `PTR` record for `50.4.128.10.in-addr.arpa.`.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Yes, I know it has to do with DNS zones, but the order in which they are written was originally an arbitrary design decision.  Had DNS been designed to use the opposite order, like Java classes, then your example hostname would be `com.mycompany.www.server456`, the rDNS lookup name for `10.128.4.50` would be `.arpa.in-addr.10.128.4.50`, and URLs would have all elements going from broader to more specific identifiers.

Comment: @WarrenYoung You're right.  In my mind, the metaphorical ordering concept extends to the components of DNS names, but since it's not a byte-ordering issue, I see how my use of the term 'endian' was confusing.  I have edited my answer to remove it.

Comment: I've removed my comments.